# AWS Lambda Return Value Specified Not in Output

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

**Scenario-1**: A lambda function outputs the returned value when executed:

[image: expected]

**Scenario-2**: A lambda function outputs `null` instead of the returned value when executed:

[image: actual]

*Why is the returned value in scenario-2 not output when the lambda is executed?*

**NOTE**: The lambda in scenario-1 will output the returned value regardless of whether the `body` property is an object or string.

Comment: And, the answer is the function in scenario-2 doesn't have the `async` keyword in it's definition. Consequently, if you employ a callback in scenario-2, this works as well as adding the `async` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

The response of scenario - 2 is `null` because of the missing `async` keyword in the exports.handler. Once you add that back, you will get the desired response